# dplyr solution to tabulate long data file

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
"year"=c(2014,2015,2016,2017,2014,2015,2016,2014,2015,2016,2017,2014,2015,2016,2017),
"grade"=c(9,10,11,12,9,10,11,9,10,11,12,9,10,11,12),
"score"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,2,0,0,1,1))
```

For each student I want to report the first score > 0 and the grade in which that occurs. If a student does not get a score > 0 then I want to report the maximum grade for that student.

My hopeful output is a table that shows the count of each score and the average grade.

I do this manually to obtain:

score = 0, count = 1, mean grade = 12

score = 1, count = 2, mean grade = 10.5

score = 2, count = 1, mean grade = 11

Answer (score 3):

After grouping by 'student', `slice` based on the condition to return rows with the first row where the 'score' is greater than 0 and `if` `all` the 'score' are 0, then return the row where the 'grade' is max (`which.max`), grouped by 'score', get the count (`n()`) and the `mean` of 'grade'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(student) %>% 
   slice(if(all(score == 0)) which.max(grade) else which.max(score > 0)) %>% 
   group_by(score) %>%
   summarise(count = n(), mean_grade = mean(grade))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  score count mean_grade
#  <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
#1     0     1       12  
#2     1     2       10.5
#3     2     1       11
```